# Write same external table query to be used in different databases inside one instance of Hive

Tags: database, hive, external-tables

I need to create an external table command for Hive. The command requires you to specify the location also.

Issue is that the same command will be used in multiple databases inside one Hive instance.

Is there a way to include Hive database name also in the query? Or some other way will also work.

Regards,

Comment: You can use `Database.Table` in all HQL commands **except ALTER**. E.g. `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.sometest ...` and `SELECT ... FROM default.sometest ...` **but** `USE default ; ALTER TABLE sometest ...`

Comment: 1. its not mandatory to include location while creating external table. 2. you can use command "use db_name;" before create statement to have new database.